# In Excel 2013 show cells as empty or blank until data is entered in other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What formula do I use to show Column C as blank until data is entered into Column B5,B6,B7, etc.?  The formula I now have shows:

```
DATE        AMOUNT PD   BALANCE
8/14/2015   $572.82     $572.82
9/17/2015   $572.82     $1,145.64
10/15/2015  $572.82     $1,718.46
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have just used an if statement to make the cell appear empty if no data is entered into it. For example

```
=IF(A1>0, A1, " ")
```

This code says that if the number in A1 is greater than zero than copy A1 to that cell, else just keep the cell blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
=If(And(Len(B5)>0,Len(B6)>0,Len(B7)>0),Sum(B5:B7),"")
```

where `Sum(B5:B7)` is the result you want to show and `""` is just a blank value.